# Rolling Average - Calendar Table and slicers

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, powerbi-embedded

I'm having an issue that i can't seem to solve on my own:

I have a model that has two tables.

**Fruit_data_Table**

- Date
- Fruit_id
- Fruit_category
- Fruit_scheduled_picking_time
- Fruit_real_picking_time
- Fruit_picked_within_1min = 1 or 0
- Fruit_picked_within_5min = 1 or 0
- etc etc

On every given day i have 700 different fruit entries on my fruit_data_table.

I created a Calendar_Table using a classic :

```
    Calendar_Table= CALENDAR(MIN(Fruit_data_Table[Date]);MAX(Fruit_data_Table[Date]))
```

And then i needed combined averaged values for any given day, including rolling averages, so inside my Calendar_Table i added some calculated columns for every dates such as :

```
    Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick= 
    VAR this_date = Calendar_Table[Date] 
    RETURN CALCULATE(
    SUM(Fruit_data_Table[Fruit_picked_within_1min ])/COUNT(Fruit_data_Table[Fruit_picked_within_1min ]);Fruit_data_Table[Date] = this_date)
```

Or a rolling average :

```
    Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick_7day_average= 
    VAR this_date = Calendar_Table[Date] 
    RETURN CALCULATE( 
       SUM(Fruit_data_Table[Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick])/COUNT(Fruit_data_Table[Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick]);
       DATESBETWEEN(Calendar_Table[Date];DATEADD(LASTDATE(Calendar_Table[Date]);-6;DAY);LASTDATE(Calendar_Table[Date])))
```

Which mean i ahve something like

**Calendar_Table**

- Date
- Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick (%)
- Fruit_on_time_1_min_pick_7day_average (%)
- etc etc

This all seems to work pretty well and i have my daily rate of fruit pciked on time and rolling averages.
The problem is that then i can't use my slicer to sort by fruit_category, or by time_of_day for example... any idea how i can get back to those slicers ?

(The PowerBi rolling average function don't seem to work at all for me, even though my Calendar_Table is a PowerBi generated Date Table...)

Thank you very much !

PS: real code is about train numbers is a major french train station... not really about fruits :)

Comment: Did you ctreate a relationship between your two tables? If not then the slicer will just filter it´s own table

Comment: there is a relationship on the dates, but that's all. I don't see what other relationship i could make